# React App on Heroku and Dyno Useage

Tags: heroku, reactjs

I was wondering if anyone knew since ReactJS components sometimes use a pollInterval to constantly refresh the DOM with new data, does this have an impact on dyno useage in Heroku? Would the app be running constantly?

Thank you.

Comment: Are the components calling out to Heroku with AJAX?

Comment: yes, they are being called by AJAX.

Comment: Then as long as someone has the page with that component active, yes, your Heroku app will be constantly running.